# Why didn't Trelawney vanish her empty sherry bottles?

Tags: harry-potter, sybill-trelawney

Professor Trelawney is somewhat notorious for her drinking habit. She often uses the Room of Requirement to try and dispose of her empty bottles.

> Harry sprinted towards [the noise], his wand at the ready, hurdled round another corner and saw Professor Trelawney sprawled upon the floor, her head covered in one of her many shawls, several sherry bottles lying beside her, one broken.
>   [...]
>   "I - well," said Professor Trelawney, drawing her shawls around her defensively and staring down at him with her vastly magnified eyes. "I wished to - ah - deposit certain - um - personal items in the Room..." And she muttered something about "nasty accusations".
>   <sub>*(Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 25, The Seer Overheard)*.</sub>

Yet there is a spell that specifically vanishes unwanted items.

> "Bill took out his wand, muttered "*Evanesco!* and the scrolls vanished.
>   <sub>*(Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 5, The Order of the Phoenix)*.</sub>

Why did she carry her bottles through the castle to the Room of Requirement when she could have simply vanished them by magic?

Comment: What if she needed them to bottle the sherry she was brewing in the room of requirement?

Comment: A) how competent is she again? B) you  try mixing drunkenness and magic, I'll get the popcorn

Comment: @Radhil: It's possible drunk-magic is as frowned upon as drinking and driving among Muggles; it is likely to be very hazardous to the user and everyone in his or her vicinity.

Comment: @RoyalCanadianBandit It seems [fairly common](http://www.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/128806/who-got-drunk-in-harry-potter) and not really frowned upon.

Comment: @TheDarkLord: Clearly, lots of wizards in HP enjoy a drink (or several). But I didn't see any examples in the list you linked of wizards *doing magic* while intoxicated.

Comment: @RoyalCanadianBandit - that was my (snarky) point in its entirety, actually. Ron does enough damage to himself sober.

Comment: @Radhil don't encourage him pls. Last time the Dark Lord got smashed he got a really ugly tattoo and killed a dozen muggles.

Answer (score 9):

## Trelawney might not have been good enough at magic to do it.

The only time that Trelawney is actually seen using magic to do anything is when she levitates crystal balls during the battle.

> “I have more!’ shrieked Professor Trelawney from over the banisters, ‘more for any who want them! Here –’
> And with a movement like a tennis serve, she heaved another enormous crystal sphere from her bag, waved her wand through the air, and caused the ball to speed across the hall and smash through a window.” 
> <sub><sup>*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 32 (The Elder Wand)*</sup></sub>

Making the crystal balls fly is the *only* example of her using magic. At that time, she would have had the most motivation to use magic, since there was a war going on around her. Still, her choice of spell even in that high-pressure moment is to float crystal balls. Levitation is one of the simpler types of magic - first-years can do it. Ron, who wasn’t particularly good at magic, especially in his early years, was able to levitate a troll’s club, which would be heavier than a crystal ball.

> “Hermione had sunk to the floor in fright; Ron pulled out his own wand – not knowing what he was going to do he heard himself cry the first spell that came into his head: ‘Wingardium Leviosa!’
>
> The club flew suddenly out of the troll’s hand, rose high, high up into the air, turned slowly over – and dropped, with a sickening crack, on to its owner’s head.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 10 (Hallowe’en)*</sup></sub>

Vanishing Spells are certainly more difficult to cast, one of the hardest O.W.L. level spells.

> “So … today we are starting Vanishing Spells. These are easier than Conjuring Spells, which you would not usually attempt until N.E.W.T. level, but they are still among the most difficult magic you will be tested on in your O.W.L.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 13 (Detention with Dolores)*</sup></sub>

If she indeed wasn’t particularly good at magic, Trelawney might not have been skilled enough to Vanish her sherry bottles.

Comment: Where do these vanished objects go? Are they completely gone or still somewhere?

Comment: @Invoker That’s answered when McGonagall has to answer it as a riddle from the Ravenclaw door knocker. **“There was a genteel tap of the knocker and the musical voice asked, again, ‘Where do vanished objects go?’
‘Into non-being, which is to say, everything,’ replied Professor McGonagall.
‘Nicely phrased,’ replied the eagle doorknocker, and the door swung open.”** *- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 30 (The Sacking of Severus Snape)*